# How to iterate over a yielded block in a Rails helper with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, block, yield, helper

I want to abstract a certain logic into a view helper. The idea is to be able to do something like this in my view:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <% pages_for_section('over') do |page| %>
    <li><%= page.menu_text %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

My current approach is to make this helper like so:

```
def pages_for_section(section_slug, &block)
  out = []

  pages_in_section = @pages.select { |p| p.section.slug == section_slug }
  pages_in_section.each do |page|
    out << yield(page)
  end

  return out
end
```

Specifically, the `out << yield(page)` part is bugging me. It works but it does not seem a very correct DRY way. Since, if I want to add a variable in my view I will need to add it to the block helper and yield call too.

Bottom line: I want to inject a variable from iterating over my pages into the yielded block. Is this a best practice or are there better and more readable alternatives?

Ideally. I would like to do something like:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <% each_page_in_section('over') do %>
    <li><%= page.menu_text %> <%= another_variable %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

With the helper looking something like this conceptually:

```
def pages_for_section(section_slug, &block)
  pages_in_section = @pages.select { |p| p.section.slug == section_slug }
  pages_in_section.each do |page|
    another_variable = "I'm cool"
    # the `page` and the `another_variable` variable will automatically 
    # be available/copied to the block
    yield
  end
end
```

Thanks.

Comment: Updated my original post to hopefully make my question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you inject, then you are going to have a yield inside an inject block.

The messiness comes from trying to both yield to a block, where the code in the block does the rendering in the view, and returning a value.  I'd only do one or the other at a time.  If you are rendering by code inside the block, don't worry about the return value.

Comment: Ok,thanks! So that's a great suggestion. However, I think I'm not clear enough in my question yet so I've added another example to try to get my idea across.